# How to start with ATG web commerce

Tags: atg

I am new to ATG web commerce. Can you help me to get pointers for good tutorials, any guidance on how to start with is, I have downloaded ATG book from oracle site. But dont know what exactly I should start with.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: Use Google, read a tutorial, dude!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get a supported environment to run ATG in, like JBoss on Windows or something similar
- Read the [Commerce Reference Store Installation Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/CRS.10-2/ATGCRSInstall/ATGCRSInstall.pdf) and follow the steps to install the CSR
- Now come back and ask any specific questions you may have.

Comment: thnx a lot... i tried google but many search results confused me... gr8 help...